# Channel in Julia

Tags: julia

I read about `channel` in julia in parallel computing. 
I realized that we can use `channel` to be able to write and read in a same time. When I wanted to try it I find out when we use `take` actually we take the top data on `channel` and then remove it from that! How another process can read that ? and how `channel` is doing parallel? and I don't know when it's good for using that and how efficient it is. 
-------------------- EDITE---------------------- :
This is a simple program for showing how to use channel for parallelisation: 
    julia> addprocs(4)
    4-element Array{Int64,1}:
     2
     3
     4
     5

```
julia> const jobs = RemoteChannel(()->Channel{Int}(32))
RemoteChannel{Channel{Int64}}(1, 1, 6)

julia> const results = RemoteChannel(()->Channel{Tuple}(32))
RemoteChannel{Channel{Tuple}}(1, 1, 7)

julia> @everywhere function do_work(jobs,results)
       while true
           job_id=take!(jobs)
           exec_time=rand()
           sleep(exec_time)
           put!(results, (job_id, exec_time, myid()))
           end
       end

julia> function make_jobs(n)
       for i in 1:n
           put!(jobs,i)
           end
       end
make_jobs (generic function with 1 method)

julia> n=12
12

julia> @schedule make_jobs(n)
Task (done) @0x00007fa873905a50

julia> for p in workers()
           @async remote_do(do_work, p, jobs, results)
       end

julia> @elapsed while n>0
       job_id, exec_time, where=take!(results)
       println("$job_id finished in $(round(exec_time,2)) seconds on worker $where")
       n=n-1
       end
4 finished in 0.13 seconds on worker 5
1 finished in 0.21 seconds on worker 4
2 finished in 0.64 seconds on worker 3
3 finished in 0.82 seconds on worker 2
6 finished in 0.72 seconds on worker 5
7 finished in 0.35 seconds on worker 3
5 finished in 0.89 seconds on worker 4
11 finished in 0.33 seconds on worker 4
10 finished in 0.61 seconds on worker 3
8 finished in 0.82 seconds on worker 2
9 finished in 0.71 seconds on worker 5
12 finished in 0.24 seconds on worker 4
0.082128167
```

I can't understand! We can use a a `for` loop instead of the function `do_work`! and then we can save it the result as an `SharedArray` and then we could parallel it by dynamic scheduling or something. 
Why we are using like this?
Actually my question is when we use like this? and why?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44987612/4183191 Mind you channels aren't about parallelisation, they're to do with Tasks (aka coroutines). (yes you can create a remote process and run a task, but that's not the point)

Comment: So It's not for parallelisation. When we use a data actually we are use and deleting it, right?And why we are iterating by channel? What is our benefits? we can do it by for loop and other stuff, Is there any benefit on it?

Comment: My answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44578892/4183191 goes into some detail :)  Or just read the relevant manual sections: [[Section on Tasks (aka Coroutines)](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/control-flow/#man-tasks-1)], [[Functions relevant to Tasks](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/parallel/#Tasks-1)], [[Channels](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing/#Channels-1)], and lastly [[Remote Channels](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing/#Channels-and-RemoteChannels-1)] which may be closer to what you had in mind.